# Switching between activities along with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have the functionality as below.

Start with Activity A -> In onCreate(), display Fragment1

In Activity 1, Fragment1, I am using getActivity() method to get the Activity instance.

Activity1

```
//replace the fragment
replaceListFragment(new Fragment1(), R.id.fragment_main_layout_container);
```

Here is the Fragment1 code.

```
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        activity = (Activity1) getActivity();
    }
```

Navigate to Activity B -> In onCreate(), display Fragment2

Activity2

```
//replace the fragment
replaceListFragment(new Fragment2(), R.id.fragment_main_layout_container);
```

Here is the Fragment2 code.

```
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        activity = (Activity2) getActivity();
    }
```

Here is my button click code in Fragment2

```
            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Activity1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

First Navigation i.e., Activity1 to Activity2 works fine.
When moved to Activity2, in Fragment2, I have a button, by clicking on that it should redirect to Activity1. As in onCreate() of Activity1, I am placing Fragment1, I thought getActivity() of Fragment1 should give Activity1's instance. But it's giving Activity2's instance at that point.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let's see the code that Fragment2 uses to call Activity A

Comment: can you show us some code? or make your question more clear.

Comment: they want to see what the button-click actually does. i bet your problem is there

Comment: You should use attach and detach method for fragment

Comment: don't worry we are not going to steal your code. feel free to paste your code here if you need help. this wont solve your problem.

Comment: My code is having lot many project dependent functionality. I am just pasting the relevant code here. Updated button click code.

Comment: why you take activity object when you can directly use getActivity() in intent?

Comment: try commenting finish() or instead on button click you can try ((Activity2)getActivity()).onBackPressed();